# Firebase realtime data base android java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can someone answer my question: Why i can't create child in root like this:

```
mDatabase.child("teams").child(uniqueIDstr).child("members").child(currentUser.getEmail()).setValue("XD");
```

because something like this is working properly:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(currentUser.getUid()).child("groups").child(uniqueIDstr).setValue("group");
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem might be, because we can't see any of the values of the variables you're showing here.  You could start by logging the values of each of these strings before using them, then show the logs so we can have an idea of what isn't working the way you expect.  Also, the code here is not checking for errors on the call to setValue, so something could be going wrong, but you'd never know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this call `child(currentUser.getEmail())`. An email address always contains at least one `.` and that character is not allowed in keys in the Firebase Realtime Database. You should actually be getting an error message when you run that code that pretty explicitly tells you this.

The common solution is to "encode" the email address, for example by remove the `.`s from it or by changing each `.` to a `,`. The latter is a neat trick, since `,` is not allowed in email addresses while it **is** allowed in Realtime Database keys.